# Changing fontsize on Windows Form

Tags: c#

I made a Windows form with a width of 800, a height of 600 and put some text and other stuff in it. After that I decided to make all fonts a little bigger. When I did that everything went bigger, even the form.
What do I have to do to make only all fonts bigger?

Comment: Which mechanism did you use to make the fonts bigger? Did you increase the DPI on your machine or did you change the value of FontSize on your controls?

Comment: This is very much by design, a side-effect of the form's AutoScaleMode property.  You can temporarily set it to None, change the font, then set it back to avoid the automatic rescaling.  After which you are likely to find out that you'll have trouble fitting text in the controls.  Font is an *ambient* property.  Same thing that happens on the user's machine when your program runs with a different video DPI setting btw.  Make sure you have a good backup when you do this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. In general you should try to post a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your problem. This then helps people to specifically answer your question rather than e.g. having to guess which method you used to increase the font size.

Comment: Commant 1:  is hard to illustrate. Comment 2: the meganism that I used to make de font bigger is selecting the form and change the fontsize in the properties. Comment 3: That is maybe the solution. I'll try that. Thank you.